# C - Int Array to Integer with Mixed Digit Numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I need to convert an integer array of size 4 into an `int`. I've seen solutions for `int` arrays that look like {1, 2, 3, 4} turn into 1234, and I've also seen ones where an array like {10, 20, 30} would turn into 102030. However, my problem is that I'll have an array that might look like {0, 6, 88, 54} and the solutions I previously mentioned only work on arrays with `int`s of the same type {e.g all one digit or all two digit}.

What should I do to solve this?

My expected output from the {0, 6, 88, 54} array would be 68854.

---

[Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459963/c-int-array-to-integer-with-mixed-digit-numbers#comment85922982_49459963) An output with zeros in the middle should keep them, i.e. {6, 0, 0, 8} would be 6008 but {0, 6, 0, 0, 8} by default would still be `6008` in `int` form. I need this in an `int` but I wouldn't mind having a string intermediate.

Comment: For `{0, 6, 88, 54}` what is your expected result?

Comment: I would use `itoa`  on each element of the array and then use `strcat` to append each string to the output string.

Comment: Is the output a string or a number?

Comment: Right. So what would the expected output be for [6, 0, 0, 8]?

Comment: An output with zeros in the middle should keep them, ie {6, 0, 0, 8} would be 6008 but {0, 6, 0, 0, 8} by default would still be 6008 in int form. I need this in an int but I wouldn't mind having a string intermediate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int res = 0;
int nums[4] = {1, 4, 3, 2}

int i = 0, temp;
for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  temp = nums[i];
  do {
    res *= 10;
  } while ((temp /= 10) > 0);


  res += nums[i];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on mixed digit numbers, only single digit numbers

Comment: @bmw417 for me it's not clear what number you expect from `{0, 6, 88, 54}`

Comment: It would be 68854

Comment: @bmw417 so I have fixed the answer and it works even with this weird example Pablo gave as an example.

Answer (score 1):

a neat solution would perhaps be to print to a string then convert the string back to an integer

```
char dummy[100];
int answer;
int input[4];

....

sprintf(dummy,"%d%d%d%d",input[0],input[1],input[2],input[3]);
answer=atoi(dummy);
```

the `sprintf` prints your integers into a string

the `atoi` converts the string into your integer, and it should be able to handle a `0` at the front.

full program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char dummy[100];
  int answer;
  int input[4]={3,4,0,345};

  sprintf(dummy,"%d%d%d%d",input[0],input[1],input[2],input[3]);
  answer=atoi(dummy);

  printf("%d\n",answer);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {0, 6, 88, 54};

    char buffer[1000] = { 0 };

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof arr / sizeof *arr; ++i)
        sprintf(buffer, "%s%d", buffer, arr[i]);

    int val = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);
    printf("%d\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

int prints `608854`.